# Vector image's right side hiding

Tags: android, svg, vector

My search vector image's right side is hiding.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="36dp"
    android:height="36dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#c2c7cc"
        android:pathData="M 19 3 C 13.488281 3 9 7.488281 9 13 C 9 15.394531 9.839844 17.589844 11.25 19.3125 L 3.28125 27.28125 L 4.71875 28.71875 L 12.6875 20.75 C 14.410156 22.160156 16.605469 23 19 23 C 24.511719 23 29 18.511719 29 13 C 29 7.488281 24.511719 3 19 3 Z M 19 5 C 23.429688 5 27 8.570313 27 13 C 27 17.429688 23.429688 21 19 21 C 14.570313 21 11 17.429688 11 13 C 11 8.570313 14.570313 5 19 5 Z"/>
</vector>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried regenerating the image ? Do you get the same results ?

Comment: Have you modified the original vector image or this is the original?

Comment: I need same result. This is a original.